# Is it possible to manually indent a line while having \setlength\parindent{0pt} in the preamble in latex? If so, how?

Tags: indentation, sharelatex, parindent

I'm aware of using \noindent instead and using linebreaks to make indents. However, I'd prefer to manually make my own indentations if possible.

Comment: `\hspace{<some length>}`. You could even do a `\newlength\mylength\setlength\mylength{\parindent}\newcommand*\myindent{\hspace{\mylength}}` and then use `\myindent` in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by “doing your own indentations”: either every paragraph is indented (possible exception are those after a title) or none is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newcommand{\myindent}[1][\normalparindent]{%
  % set \parindent in a group and issue \indent
  % the setting will be forgotten at the end of the group
  {\parindent=#1\indent}\ignorespaces
}

\edef\normalparindent{\the\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\myindent \lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\myindent[3cm] \lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]